# Trouble with using Latex with R markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

Hey I'm trying to use some latex in an R markdown file but I'm getting this `error`:

> Try other LaTeX engines instead (e.g., xelatex) if you are using pdflatex. For R Markdown users, see https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html
>
> Error: Failed to compile M5_collab.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See M5_collab.log for more info.
>   In addition: There were 33 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
>   Execution halted

I've checked out the bookdown website and I've installed `tinytex`

```
install.packages("tinytex")
```

Can someone let me know what's going wrong? How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: If you're using RStudio, when you go to Tools > Global Options > Sweave, there's a preference for what typesetting system to use. What does it say, and what options do you see?

Comment: @Gregor hey thanks for the reply, it was on pdflatex at first and then I tested xelatex and that didn't work too.

Comment: Is your issue specific to the document you are working on, or is it general? For example, if you open a new Rmd document with the default template and compile to PDF, does it work?

Comment: yes I've used Rmarkdown before and I'm able to make PDF's. I think the issue is something to do with Latex and pdf on my computer?? I just knitted the document and it worked for HTML.

Comment: Installing the `tinytex` package does not guarantee a working TeX installation. You either have to install TeXLive/MikTeX/MacTeX separately or TinyTeX using ` tinytex::install_tinytex()`.

Comment: Just tried tinytex tinytex::install_tinytex() same error as before

Comment: If you've used Rmarkdown before and you are able to make PDFs, then  it sounds like the issue is specific to *this file*. It would be great if you could narrow it down to a particular line that causes the problem, and posting a minimal example illustrating the problem. Maybe then you could get fewer than 33 warnings and post the warnings too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem as you.

In my case I wanted to generate a pdf file and received this message you received.

I solved the problem of defining latex_engine as follows:

```
---
title: "Report"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---
```

Comment: I'm facing with the same problem too. I've just installed the `tinytex package` and despite I've applied the solution proposed here, the errore is keepoing on turning back